# Extract Student number

Tags: data-analysis, knime

I have excel data which contains many columns, one column called Description has the following data, I want to extract student number from each row using KNIME

Example below are three different rows

```
Being Settlement of exam fee, student Number IMIS/C/5946/7/5/2021/5690 in respect of Flora Hamis
Being Settlement of school fee, student Number IMIS/C/28727/14/7/2022/28980 in respect of Tony Alex
Being Settlement of Life Assurance, student Number  IMIS/C/28020/23/6/2022/28279 in respect of Richard Nixon
```

Here is my attempt

`regexReplace($Description$,^IMIS/\w{1}/\d/\d/\d/\d\s? ,"$1" )`

Comment: You added `{1}` (after `\w`) to macht only 1 character, but `\d` will match only one digit, so you have to change that to `\d*` (or `\d+`) to match more digits.

Comment: I do see only 4 times a `\d`, but there seems to be 5 parts with digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
/\bIMIS\/C\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+\/\d+\b/gm
```

Try it here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DSpPdk/2)